# Databinding winform code with error "InvalidCastException was unhandled"

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am doing a data binding winform with C# to connect with Northwind database
The goal is to provide the data at the winform gridview and when i click each cell, the data will be display in the respective textbox.

```
class Connection        
{   

    String connectionstring = "Data Source=ECHREIPCPC0671\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"; 

    public ArrayList GetAllProduct(int ProductID)
    {   
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)) {
            connection.Open();

            String query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID = " + ProductID;
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                var list = new ArrayList();
                while (reader.Read()) 
                {
                    String productname = reader.GetString(1);
                    String quantityperunit = reader.GetString(2);
                    Decimal unitprice = reader.GetDecimal(3);

                    list.Add(productname);
                    list.Add(quantityperunit);
                    list.Add(unitprice);

                }
                connection.Close();
                reader.Close();
                return list;
            }
```

This is the new class I added to read and fetch the data to the winform, Here when I execute the code, there is always the error

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

After the code :  `String quantityperunit = reader.GetString(2);

What should I correct my code? Does anybody can help me?

PS: At the form1.cs, I added the function to use the member in this class.

```
        private void FillTextfield(int ProductID)
    {
        list = sqlCon.GetAllProduct(ProductID);
        textProductName.Text = list[0].ToString();
        textQuantityPerUnit.Text = list[1].ToString();
        textUnitPrice.Text = list[2].ToString();

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        int currentIndex = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[currentRowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        FillTextfield(currentIndex);
    }

}
```

I don't think the quantityperunit is an int type, because the data inside this cell is something like "12oz bottles" and so on

Comment: What is the type of your third column and what is the cell values?

Comment: In the data grid view, I have 4 columns, productID, ProductName, QuantityPerUnit and UnitPrice, in database the types are int, nvarchar(40), nvarchar(20), money.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String quantityperunit=reader.GetString(2).ToString();
```

`reader.GetString(2)` is fetching you some integer data and you're trying to put that data into a string variable, which will throw you an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The quantityperunit is an integer type.

```
int quantityperunit = int.Parse(reader.GetString(2).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'"

You may try this ..

```
String quantityperunit=reader.GetInt32(2).ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you, if I tried to your code, then at the next line, another error came out" Specified cast is not valid." Does it mean the converting from money type in database to decimal was wrong?

Comment: Hi~ Thank you for the advice, but the next one was a moneytype in SQL, I wanna use                                      String unitprice = reader.GetSqlMoney(3).ToString(); But it still doesn't work, do u have some new idea?